# Sum of items from start date to end date in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3

I am trying to get the sum of expense from start date to end date.

```
monthStartDate = moment().startOf('month').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
monthEndDate = moment().endOf('month').format('YYYY-MM-DD');

this.monthExpense = this.expenseProvider.getExpenseValue().valueChanges();
this.monthExpense.subscribe(ref =>
  ref.startAt(this.monthStartDate).endAt(this.monthEndDate))    
}
```

I want to get the total of expenseAmount from these date ranges. Following is the Firebase DB structure screenshot

[image: firebase_database]

Any help shall be great

Comment: are you getting desired data? i thinks you need to query the `list` than doing it in the subscribe. can yo show your `.getExpenseValue()` code?

Comment: `getExpenseValue(): AngularFireList<any>{
      return this.afDatabase.list(`/userProfile/${this.userId}/expenseList`)
    }`

Answer (score 1):

Do query in your service.ts

```
getExpenseValue(monthStartDate, monthEndDate): AngularFireList<any>{ 
    return this.afDatabase.list('/userProfile/${this.userId}/expenseList' ,
        ref => ref.startAt(monthStartDate).endAt(monthEndDate)) 
}
```

And in your component.ts

`totalExpense:number;` //declaration

```
monthStartDate = moment().startOf('month').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
monthEndDate = moment().endOf('month').format('YYYY-MM-DD');

this.totalExpense = 0;//reset
this.monthExpense = this.expenseProvider.getExpenseValue(this.monthStartDate,this.monthEndDate);
this.monthExpense.snapshotChanges()
  .map(actions => {
    return actions.map(a=>{
        a.payload.val().expense.forEach(res=>{
            this.totalExpense += res.expenseAmount;
        }
        return this.totalExpense;
    })
  });
```

Comment: I am getting the value `0` on `console.log(this.totalExpense)`

Comment: do `console.log(a.payload.val())` inside `actions.map` and check your query returns data

Comment: or try this in your html `<p>{{monthExpense | async | json}}</p>`

Comment: my mistake i thought you are querying `expenes` node. so here you get each doc with multiple expenses under `expenes`. you need to do a foreach to get the values.

Comment: Still the answer remains `0` or `null`

Comment: i have a feeling that your query with date is not working. to check that replace `getExpenseValue()` function with `return this.afDatabase.list('/userProfile/${this.userId}/expenseList')`. and inside `actions.map(a=>{...`  just console `a.payload.val()`. if it printing the value try with adding the query part and check. and dont forget to add `<p>{{monthExpense | async | json}}</p>` in your template other ways you need to subscribe to the observable.

Comment: `this.monthExpense = this.expenseProvider.getMonthExpense(this.monthStartDate, this.monthEndDate).valueChanges();
    this.monthExpense.subscribe( ref => ref
      .forEach(expense =>{
        this.monthlyExpense(expense.expenseAmount)
      })
    );`    The method was correct, the total must have been done just after ref